# Dynamically generate a table within a row of a table

Tags: jsf, datatable, seam

I have a SEAM 2, JSF 1.2 web application with a Java back end.   Currently I have table that displays books (see below).  What I need to add to this is a collapse-able table to each of these rows that would show previous versions of this book (#{_item.relatedVersions}).  Each of these version are a book themselves (but don't have an expandable sub-version table, i.e only 1 level deep on a nested table).  So what I am wondering is what is the cleanest way to display a list of books (#{bean.items}) in "Table A", and then foreach book dynamically generate another Table within a row in "Table A"?

...

```
<a:form id="bookList_results_form">
       <rich:dataTable id="bookList_dt"
                    rendered="#{bean.itemCount gt 0}"
                    var="_item"
                    width="100%"
                    value="#{bean.items}">

           <rich:column>
               <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{_item.bookId}"/>
           </rich:column>

           <rich:column>

            <a:commandButton image="#{plusIcon}" size="15" 
            title="Expand version info."
            action="#{bean. ???}"
            ajaxSingle="true" bypassUpdates="true" immediate="true"/>

            <f:facet name="header">Book Name</f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{_item.bookName}" escape="true"/>
           </rich:column>

           <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Comments</f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{_item.comments}"/>
           </rich:column>

           <rich:column>

            <f:facet name="header">Actions</f:facet>
            <a:commandLink
                value="Edit"
                title="View or Edit metadata for this book"
                action="#{bean.edit(_item.bookId)}"/>

           </rich:column>
       </rich:dataTable>
</a:form>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to use the `<rich:subTable>`?

Edit: I've updated main parts of my answer to show a more detailed example:

```
<rich:dataTable id="bookList_dt" [...] var="_item" value="#{bean.items}" >
  <f:facet name="header">
    <rich:column>
      Header1
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
      Header2
    </rich:column>
  </f:facet>

  <rich:column>
    <a4j:commandLink id="toggleIcon" action="#{bean.toggleRelatedVisible(_item)}" reRender="bookList_dt">
      <h:graphicImage value="/img/plusIcon.gif" rendered="#{not bean.isRelatedVisible(_item)}" style="margin-right:4px;" />
      <h:graphicImage value="/img/minusIcon.gif" rendered="#{bean.isRelatedVisible(_item)}" style="margin-right:4px;" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
    <h:outputText value="#{_item.bookId}"/>
  </rich:column>
  [...]
  <rich:subTable value="#{_item.relatedVersions}"
                 var="_relatedItem" 
                 rendered="#{bean.isRelatedVisible(_item)}">
    <rich:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{_relatedItem.bookId}"/>
    </rich:column>
    [...]
  </rich:subTable>
</rich:dataTable>
```

In this solution I'm rerendering the whole table on collapse/expand of the subtable. Maybe you can find a more effective way.

Of course, the `bean` must have some collection of boolean-values containing the state (collapsed/expended) of the subtables.

Comment: I have not implmented it so that it looks like it generally works.  Though I can't seem to get the toggle working for the subTable.  Is there somethig I need to wrap it in?

Comment: Thats one way of doing it.  Would javaScript work as well? If so, what would it look like?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=subTableToggleControl&skin=blueSky

```
<h:form>
    <rich:dataTable value="#{carsBean.inventoryVendorLists}" var="list">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <rich:columnGroup>
                <rich:column colspan="6">
                    <h:outputText value="Cars marketplace" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
                    <h:outputText value="Model" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Price" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Mileage" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="VIN Code" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Items stock" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Days Live" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:columnGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <rich:column colspan="6">
            <rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler for="sbtbl" />
            <h:outputText value="#{list.vendor}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:collapsibleSubTable value="#{list.vendorItems}" var="item" id="sbtbl" expandMode="client">
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.model}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.price}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.mileage}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.vin}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.stock}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.daysLive}" />
            </rich:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:outputText value="Total of #{list.vendor} Cars: #{list.count}" />
            </f:facet>
        </rich:collapsibleSubTable>
    </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I am running rich faces 3.x abd I don't have access to rich:collapsibleSubTable.  So I am trying to use collapsible subTable, but I am having trouble writing the javaScript toggler for it

Comment: Well this should be usable if you use RichFace 3.4-Snapshot atleast.

Comment: True, though I get an error stating it doesn't reconqnize the tag :( believe me, I would love to use this!